# BPF verifier says program exceeds 1M instruction

Tags: c, linux-kernel, ebpf, xdp-bpf

For the following program I get an error from the verifier saying that it exceeds 1M instructions, even though it shouldn't. The program finds the hostname of a HTTP packet.

```
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>

struct server_name {
    char server_name[256];
    __u16 length;
};

#define MAX_SERVER_NAME_LENGTH 253
#define HEADER_LEN 6

SEC("xdp")
int collect_ips_prog(struct xdp_md *ctx) {
    char *data_end = (char *)(long)ctx->data_end;
    char *data = (char *)(long)ctx->data;
    int host_header_found = 0;

    for (__u16 i = 0; i <= 512 - HEADER_LEN; i++) {
        host_header_found = 0;

        if (data_end < data + HEADER_LEN) {
            goto end;
        }

        // Elf loader does not allow NULL terminated strings, so have to check each char manually
        if (data[0] == 'H' && data[1] == 'o' && data[2] == 's' && data[3] == 't' && data[4] == ':' && data[5] == ' ') {
            host_header_found = 1;
            data += HEADER_LEN;
            break;
        }

        data++;
    }

    if (host_header_found) {
        struct server_name sn = {"a", 0};

        for (__u16 j = 0; j < MAX_SERVER_NAME_LENGTH; j++) {
            if (data_end < data + 1) {
                goto end;
            }

            if (*data == '\r') {
                break;
            }

            sn.server_name[j] = *data++;
            sn.length++;
        }
    }

end:
    return XDP_PASS;
}
```

Ignore that `data` is not pointing to the beginning of the HTTP payload of a packet. This is enough to reproduce the problem I'm seeing.

I get the following error:

```
; for (__u16 j = 0; j < MAX_SERVER_NAME_LENGTH; j++) {
76: (25) if r3 > 0xfb goto pc+3
77: (07) r3 += 1
78: (07) r4 += 8
79: (3d) if r1 >= r4 goto pc-15

from 79 to 65: R0_w=fp-189 R1=pkt_end(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R2=pkt(id=0,off=280,r=363,imm=0) R3_w=invP76 R4_w=pkt(id=0,off=363,r=363,imm=0) R5_w=inv(id=0,umin_value=1,umax_value=65536,var_off=(0x0; 0x1ffff)) R10=fp0 fp-8=??????mm fp-16=00000000 fp-24=00000000 fp-32=00000000 fp-40=00000000 fp-48=00000000 fp-56=00000000 fp-64=00000000 fp-72=00000000 fp-80=00000000 fp-88=00000000 fp-96=00000000 fp-104=00000000 fp-112=00000000 fp-120=00000000 fp-128=00000000 fp-136=00000000 fp-144=00000000 fp-152=00000000 fp-160=00000000 fp-168=00000000 fp-176=00000000 fp-184=00000000 fp-192=0000mmmm fp-200=mmmmmmmm fp-208=mmmmmmmm fp-216=mmmmmmmm fp-224=mmmmmmmm fp-232=mmmmmmmm fp-240=mmmmmmmm fp-248=mmmmmmmm fp-256=mmmmmmmm fp-264=mmmmmmmm
; if (*data == '\r') {
65: (bf) r4 = r2
66: (0f) r4 += r3
67: (71) r5 = *(u8 *)(r4 +6)
BPF program is too large. Processed 1000001 insn
processed 1000001 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 34 total_states 10376 peak_states 7503 mark_read 3
```

This doesn't make sense because there should be at most 20 instructions in the second for loop, which would make for a max of 5060 instructions if the max iterations are reached. The smallest value I can decrease `MAX_SERVER_NAME_LENGTH` to for the verifier to pass is 104. If I comment out the `if (host_header_found) {` block, then the verifier succeeds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR.** Your program is too complex for the verifier to analyze, as it must iterate over more than 1 million instructions to verify the full program.

---

**Verifier Error Explanation**

> BPF program is too large. Processed 1000001 insn

The verifier errors because it already analyzed 1 million instructions. Hence it reached the limit and is giving up.

This verifier error is indeed a bit misleading. The BPF program isn't actually too large. The number of instructions the verifier has to analyze is different from the number of instructions in the whole program because **the verifier has to analyze each and every path through the program**. Therefore, it may analyze the same instruction several times, along different paths.

**How can such a small program require more than 1M analyzed instructions?**

The verifier reached 1 million instructions because your program has a lot of different paths. Indeed, your program has two loops with fairly high bounds (506 and 253), which themselves contain several conditions (to simplify, ~2 in each). In the worst case, the verifier may have to analyze each instruction on all possible paths through those two loops.

**How can I fix it?**

You may reduce the size of the loop (as you figured) to reduce the complexity. You may also simplify the loop bodies.

Alternatively, you could break your program with tail calls. Maybe one tail call between the two loops would be enough to pass the verifier.

Comment: Does XDP offload support tailing?

Comment: You'd have to ask your NIC vendor. If it's Netronome, last I checked (2 years ago), they did not.

Comment: My first loop has 506 iterations and my second loop has 253 iterations. Even if each loop did its max iterations, I'm confused how any path could result in 1M total instructions.

Comment: @user2233706 not only the number of iterations is a factor, but if possible execution paths are dependant on external data like from the packet and maps, that the verifier will also check for permutations of that external data. So it might loop for ~700 iterations for a large number of permutation of the packet. Adding extra checks might help here. For example, if you return from the program on invalid input very early in the program, the verifier doesn't have to loop for all of those permutations. So try to exit as soon as you can, handle any error conditions first.

Comment: @DylanReimerink I think that's bad advice. The verifier will still have to check all possible paths through the program, so adding more conditions will just increase the number of paths.

Comment: @user2233706 You have to consider that the number of path grows exponentially with the number of conditions. For example, a program with only two independent conditions has four different paths. You can check that with toy examples.

Comment: @pchaigno perhaps my understanding of the verifier is flawed. I thought that if there are less possible inputs that the verifier has to enumerate less to convince itself code is safe.

Comment: Perhaps using a string search algorithm like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm could help reduce the amount of loop iterations needed to find a string match

Comment: @DylanReimerink Thanks, I'll try that algorithm, but I think it'll fail the verifier because of the inner for loop. From what I've seen, all loops must use a constant for the end condition.

Comment: When doing a tail call, I want to pass the current ```data``` pointer along with other information to ```bpf_tail_call```. I created my own struct for this, but I get error ```R1 type=fp expected=ctx```.